# Is it possible to start/pause video in Windows Media Player using the keyboard

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I am frequently listening to tecnical video presentations (for example, from .NET Rocks TV) on my netbook. I watch a portion of the video, click the pause button using the mouse, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to my open Visual Studio and do somecoding, then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> back to [Windows Media Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player) (WMP), mouse click to restart the video (repeat every 1-2 minutes).

The mouse clicks to start/pause the video on Windows Media Player is annoying. Is there a key combination that can be used to start/stop the video when the Windows Media Player window has focus?

I am on Windows 7 if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ctrl-P](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/knowledgecenter/keyboard_shortcuts/player10.mspx), but I assume it'll only work when focused. Can't test it out, I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: It works but indeed only when WMP has the focus.

Answer (score 5):

Install [**WMPKeys**](http://wmpkeys.sourceforge.net/) and you'll be able to define global hotkeys for the many controls of Windows Media Player. I just tested it and it works with WMP12 included in Windows 7.

WMP doesn't even have to have the focus, the hotkeys will work globally anywhere in Windows.

[image]

It should also be possible to define hotkeys in [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to control Windows Media Player.

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic11117.html is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: WMPKeys doesn't appear to work on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Windows Media Player Plus!**](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/index.htm?http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/) plugin should also be able to help:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Your keyboard might have a multimedia key that lets you Play/Pause media files. These media keys work regardless of application focus.

If your keyboard doesn't have a Play/Pause media key, you can create one for windows using SharpKeys.