# how to script my own "pause" button for windows media player?

Tags: autohotkey, windows-media-player

I want some way to create a shortcut button to pause windows media player. My keyboard doesn't come with a puase/play button, so I want to find a free way to mimic that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script worked for me:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Recommended for catching common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#Esc::Media_Play_Pause
```

But [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/65916/47272) also covers other options

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use AHK and keep it running (unless of course you're using it for other reasons as well). A key remapper app like [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com) should also be able to help, by allowing you to remap any unused key to act as Play/Pause:

[image: 1]

This way, no extra process needs to keep running in the background.